# symfony contact form is submitted but emails dont arrive

Tags: symfony, smtp, symfony4, mailer

I need some help regarding sending emails in symfony 4.

I made a contact form in symfony 4.
where i use formbuilder and swiftmailer. The contact form works, it validates and i can submit. but emails don't arrive plus i don't get a confirmation message on the contactpage itself after sending.
i use mailer with host of the website itself. The website is in production mode.

See below the code i used. Maybe i missed some settings? thanks in advance!

ContactType.php

```
<?php
// your-path-to-types/ContactType.php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name',TextType::class);
        $builder->add('email',EmailType::class);
        $builder->add('subject',TextType::class);
        $builder->add('body',TextareaType::class);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'contact';
    }
}
```

Contact.php my entity

```
<?php

// src/Entity/Contact.php


namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;  

class Contact

{

    protected $name;
    protected $email;
    protected $subject;
    protected $body;
    public function getName()

    {
        return $this->name;
    }



    public function setName($name)

    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }



    public function getEmail()

    {
        return $this->email;
    }



    public function setEmail($email)

    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }



    public function getSubject()

    {
        return $this->subject;
    }



    public function setSubject($subject)

    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }



    public function getBody()

    {
        return $this->body;
    }



    public function setBody($body)

    {
        $this->body = $body;

    }

    public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
    {
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('name', new NotBlank());

        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('email', new Email());

        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new NotBlank());
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new Length(array('max'=> 50)));

        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('body', new Length(array('min'=> 5)));
    }

}
```

and my controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Contact;
use App\Form\ContactType;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;


final class PagesController extends DefaultController

{


    /**
     * @Route("/contact", name="contact")
     * @Method("GET|POST")
     */
    public function contact(Request $request,  \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {

        $enquiry = new Contact();
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $enquiry);

         $this->request = $request;
            if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {


                        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
                            ->setFrom('contact@example.com')
                            ->setTo('xxxxxxx@gmail.com')
                            ->setBody($this->renderView('contact/contactEmail.txt.twig', array('enquiry' => $enquiry)));
                        $mailer->send($message);

                    $this->get('session')->getFlashbag('blog-notice', 'Your contact enquiry was successfully sent. Thank you!');


                // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
                // the form if they refresh the page
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact'));

            }
        }

        return $this->render('pages/contact.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }


}
```

and in my *main.env* file i have this

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://localhost:25?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=xxx&password=xxxx
```

So email does not get delivered. After submit I am transferred back to contact page, and no flash message either :/
Have I missed anything else for this to work?

***example:***

- does my username have to be a whole email address that I also need to decode, etc?
- do I need to change something on the server also? please advise.

Comment: Now the site is it already in production, so in dev mode it works and don't give the same problem? How does the swiftmailer configuration looks?

Comment: I actually did everything in production mode. didn't test it in dev mode.

my swiftmailler is only this:

swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }

Comment: show your swiftmailer config please

Comment: Is your form valid and pass the condition ? do you have some return when you call `send($message)` that could indicate an error ? Not related to your issue, why not using `redirectToRoute('contact')` instead of `redirect($this->generateUrl('contact'))` ?

Comment: `code 'swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }  code`
    ----> is my swift mailer config.. i didn't change anything yet

Comment: @Etshy: i just followed a tutorial.  my form checks the condition and gives them also when not meet them. so after i meet them email check, lenght check it sort of sends i guess.

Comment: do you use gmail  smtp as sender mailer ?

Comment: no the mail settings are from the website itself. I use the settings form a mail account from the website. me@website.com  + password

Comment: can you try with the gmail , because there is a layer security , for example for gmail you have to activate the app secure less in your gmail account , like that , you are given your application the permission to send email by you gmail account , if this work fine , that means ,the problem is not inside your code but in your smtp configuration

Comment: okay thats good to check.i will set that up

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i set up the gmail account for now. and yes it sent an email now :)

So my code was alright i guess. just server settings not good, but works with gmail now :)
Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another question related to the email setup. By changing to a gmail setup i have my gmail address as sender. But i want to use the website address as sender (like a no-reply@)

How does this work? how do i set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Alright i can answer my own original question.

I got the smtp to work:

in the swiftmailer.yaml it put the following, and i disabled the mailer in yaml.

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:        smtp
    username:         null
    password:         null
    host:             localhost
    port:             465
    encryption:       ssl
    auth-mode:        login
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed: true
            verify_peer: false
            verify_peer_name: false
```

Emails arrive in my mailbox where sender is the xxx@website.com